# How do I get a uniqueness validation to pass in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to get a uniqueness validation to work on one of my models in Rails 5 following the RoR Guides. However, my records aren't saving in the console and are being rejected as if they already existed (they don't).

In my Model:

```
class Container < ApplicationRecord

validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

Then in the console:

```
2.3.3 :001> Container.create(name:"totally_unique_name")
```

which returns

```
Container Exists (2.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "containers" WHERE "containers"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "totally_unique_name"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: Maybe it does already exist? What does `Container.all` in the console give you ?

Comment: Try using `create!` (notice the `!`) in the console so you see the ActiveModel Errors that lead to the failed attempt to persist in DB

Comment: When I `Container.all` I noticed that I had quite a few nil values from previous tests of other validations. I just wiped my development DB and it seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

`Container.create`
was running into issues with previous seeds of the DB that resulted in multiple nil values.
To delete the records and refresh the development database, in the console:

```
Container.delete_all
```

This solved the mysterious uniqueness error in the model.